# Why is it OK not to strict questions-answers ratio? Only when question is lower than answers

Tags: discussion

I see users with 2 questions, but 500+ answers. But I see users with 300+ questions but no answers.

I figured StackOverflow thought about that because I saw those examples not a few times. But is it really OK? Is a good answer as good as a good question? It might sounds equal because the only difference is question and answer.

In short: I just need to know the explanation to why there isn't strict ratio between questions and answers.

Comment: Why *should* there be a strict ratio enforced?

Comment: Some questions get answered, some don't. Some get answered more than once. Most don't.

Comment: @JayBlanchard He's asking why users ask questions but never answer them, or answer questions but never ask them.  He's not talking about the number of answers per question.

Comment: Ah - I read it wrong. Or my brain scrambled it. Probably the latter.

Comment: I have over 100 answers and 8 questions. Is this a problem? Both are contributing to the community.

Comment: see: [I only ask questions. Am I unwanted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108049/i-only-ask-questions-am-i-unwanted)

Comment: I've only asked one question ever, because I know how to search. Should I be forced to post lazy dupes to be able to help people?

Comment: I am nearing 10k answers. I posted 2 questions (both self-answered). What *point* would there be in restricting my answering? Are my answers somehow not welcome because I didn't ask enough questions?

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's pretty obvious why I asked it, I meant it about those who ask too many questions but no answers at all.

Comment: @KugBuBu: how come you didn't answer 2 or 3 Meta questions before asking this?\

Comment: @KugBuBu: no, then we'd only get low-quality nonsense answers just to be able to ask a question. Us answerers need people asking questions just as much question askers need people answering.

Comment: @Servy It'll improve the activity, that isn't needed more than it does have. But asking 300 questions and no answers is type of exploiting the site, isn't?

Comment: @KugBuBu: You yourself now have asked 3 questions here on Meta. Go answer some questions here, then come back! (and see if that works for you).

Comment: @KugBuBu: **Why** is that exploiting the site? Are those questions of bad quality? We care about individual posts much more than about users. If someone asks 300 good-quality questions, **why is that abuse**?

Comment: @Wooble This site is discussing about how the site works. I know nothing about it, most of the answerers here are very old users or supervisitors or whatever.

Comment: @KugBuBu: See, that's what we want on Stack Overflow too. Experts answering. Not clueless people that should be asking the questions instead. Just like the very old users (== experts) answer here on Meta.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's a question that is hard for me to answer, because you feel that someone exploit someone because you have that feeling. There's nothing logical behind it.

Comment: @KugBuBu If people are asking lots of *bad* questions, then yes.  It's a problem.  There are tools such as the question ban, and rate limiting of questions in place to attempt to deal with this (with some degree of success).  Of course, as Martijn has said, the problem is with people posting lots of *bad* questions.  If people are posting lots of good questions, then it's not a problem at all.

Comment: @KugBuBu: That's not enough for basing rules on. You'll need to come up with actual data, not just your feeling that asking a lot of questions is abuse. Show us actual problems!

Comment: If you feel you're being exploited, **don't answer** questions from people who only ask. The community as a whole doesn't feel exploited, or we'd all leave.

Comment: @MartijnPieters (I don't have something to say on the previous comment, you are right) This isn't abuse because the activity is pretty good here, this is exploiting to personal uses. Because there aren't a lot like that but there is some.

Comment: @KugBuBu So all of the millions of people constantly finding answers to their questions in SO posts through Google searches are exploiting users because they're not contributing anything either, right?

Comment: @Wooble I once suggested to open a wiki as sub-site that is only on programming that will give more information about those subjects in it than wikipedia and etc. There were a comment that got a lot of votes that said that it's building a community from a scratch or something like that, that is hard work.

Comment: @Servy That's a good one, they exploit Google, but Google uses them to data mining. This is a win-win situation.

Comment: @KugBuBu There you go.  That's how the site works.  Good questions and good answers benefit everyone involved.  That's not exploitation, it's just goodness.

Comment: @Servy SO can my parents I see. I think I got it why it isn't a good idea to put questions-answers ratio.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I just need to know the explanation to why there isn't strict ratio between questions and answers.

Why should there be? Different people have different reasons for using Stack Overflow. Some people are here to *ask* questions and find solutions to their problems. Some people are here to *answer* such questions and thus help the community. **Stack Overflow requires both good questions and good answers.** Without good questions, there won't be useful answers and without good answers, those questions will have no use.

It's perfectly fine to not have a strict answer-to-questions ratio. In fact, it'd do more harm than good. It may discourage an active contributor contributing if they're forced to ask/answer questions when they don't really need to.

Comment: StackOverflow is very strict to new users. If you aren't born with the instict knowledge to know that you need to read every little line here you are doomed.

Comment: @KugBuBu: don't you think forcing newbies to find questions they know how to answer before they were allowed to ask their own would be even harder on them?

Comment: @KugBuBu And yet all of us active users managed it just fine.  It's clearly not impossible.  It's hard, sure.  Many people are either incapable, or unwilling, to figure out how to use the site effectively.  That's fine.  The site isn't for everyone.  The vast majority of programmers can get by never ever posting on the site, and still benefit greatly from it by simply finding great questions though Google.  That's the *goal* of the site.

Comment: @Wooble You can make it less strict by allowing a few in the start.

Comment: @Servy I made a few mistakes on the start that the question itself isn't good unless you change them to whole new question, and another that I could improve to get out of the question ban. I barely got out of it. Isn't it strict? If that question was something like the first one I was screwed.

Comment: @KugBuBu It's a *necessary* tool to deal with the droves of users coming here to ask awful question and that have no interest or ability in improving their contributions.

Comment: @Servy It's too strict, I didn't knew how important it was to read how to ask at first. (At least warning is needed)

Comment: @KugBuBu You weren't able to post any questions at all until confirming that you'd read "how to ask".  You actually *did* get warnings, you just ignored them.  If there were even more warnings, you'd undoubtably have ignored them too.

Comment: @Servy I couldn't knew how important it was to actually read it. You read terms and agreements? Me neither. I inherited the same behaviour.

Comment: @KugBuBu So what makes you think yet another warning would have changed a thing?  When a user is determined to ignore all warnings, they're determined to ignore all warnings.  Nothing you can say/do will change that.

Comment: @Servy When you get a downvote they can put warning at the top of the site that explains that the user is getting closer to question ban and is should read how to ask (again) before it. I think I wouldn't ignore that. I didn't even knew about that question ban.

Comment: @KugBuBu You ignored all of the other warnings you got.  Why would that one be any different?

Comment: @Servy I editted that comment, I didn't knew about the question ban thing until it occurred. I was that clueless.

Comment: @KugBuBu Because you choose to ignore all of the warnings that you were given.  Again, why would *yet another* warning be any different?  We put plenty of information in front of new users.  Virtually all of it is categorically ignored.  Adding more changes nothing.

Comment: @Servy Red big text at the top of the website will change something. When I asked in first time for me it was just a wall of text. I just searched the question if didn't found a duplicate I wrote the question. I wasn't that ignorant if the site said something I would ignore, I just thought it wasn't that important to know how to ask tah it'll lead to question ban. I don't think the discussion here is moving.